# I keep getting an "Authentication Required" popup on Ripple Emulator preventing me from registering a new user with Parse

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework, ripple

I am trying to build a basic user registration page for a cross-platform mobile application using the Cordova Ionic Framework, AngularJS and Parse.

When I make a JavaScript call to register a new user with Parse, I get a popup message that reads "Authentication Required - The server http://localhost:4400 requires a username and password. The server says: Parse".

I have used fiddler to check what the actual request and response is and the request is being made to the url: http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=https%3A//api.parse.com/1/users

The JSON response is error=unauthorized

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 and using Ripple as an Emulator and I am following the basic tutorial [here](http://www.joshmorony.com/user-authentication-with-ionic-and-parse-part-1-email-login/).

I have already checked that my Application ID and JavaScript ID is correct in the Parse Initializer. The Angular function is as basic as it could be:

```
$scope.signupEmail = function () {

    //Create a new user on Parse
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", $scope.data.username);
    user.set("password", $scope.data.password);
    user.set("email", $scope.data.email);

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function (user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Ripple settings.
On the Ripple Emulator one can change settings and one of the settings is "Cross Domain Proxy". Cross Domain Proxy has three options: "Disabled", "Local" and "Remote".  Selecting "Disabled" resolved the problem.